# Unable to create Web App for Containers - resourceId length is too short:

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I try to create a **Web App for Containers** using the Azure Portal but I am unable to apply the "Configure container" blade. No matter what Image source I try to select, the container button keeps spinning and doesn't return:

[image]

Here is the error I see in the Google Chrome console:

```
main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1 Error: resourceId length is too short: 
    at new e (main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1)
    at e.validateContainerImage (functions.azure.com/ng-min/1.044a6c8d0435c0124e13.chunk.js:1)
    at e._validateContainerImage (functions.azure.com/ng-min/1.044a6c8d0435c0124e13.chunk.js:1)
    at e.applyContainerConfig (functions.azure.com/ng-min/1.044a6c8d0435c0124e13.chunk.js:1)
    at t.clickApply (functions.azure.com/ng-min/1.044a6c8d0435c0124e13.chunk.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (functions.azure.com/ng-min/1.044a6c8d0435c0124e13.chunk.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1)
    at Jr (main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1)
    at main.9b48674960c2e585cd46.bundle.js:1
```

I already tried different browsers and face the issue since last week. Any ideas?

Comment: this is on the web app blade, right?

Comment: yes, on the "Configure container" blade when you create the Web App for container

Comment: but wait, on the create blade for the webapp, or on the existing webapp blade? seems like the former? yeah, it doesnt seem to work for me as well. getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is what I got from an MS employee:

> With the recent change in the portal to new full screen create
>   experience, the Web App for Containers portal creation entry point
>   regressed.
>
> For now the workaround is to instead click into the Web App create
>   experience, and choose "Docker Image" (Linux or Windows) in the
>   "Publish" option.  The create wizard will then lead you to the image
>   selection UX (click "Next: Docker" button at the bottom) where you can
>   then choose the same options that were available before in the Web App
>   for Containers experience.
>
> We are also working on changing the Web App for Containers package to
>   instead point to the new full screen web app create experience but
>   with the selections already defaulted to "Docker Image".

so I guess nothing you can really do, except the mentioned workaround

Comment: Insane. Using the Web App dialog I was able to create it. Thank you!

Comment: bughappens ;)))